# rocking effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects

Is it possible to create a rocking effect in jquery?To be honest I can't imagine how it could work but I am relatively new to jquery and it's always better to ask.

http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/9049/63148139.jpg

as you can imagine the square(in 3 stages) should move on the line.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any examples? This is a very vague question.

Comment: What do you mean by "rocking effect"?

Comment: @Andy ... animated ponyes playing rock'n'roll ...

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to be more specific. It's good to ask, but you have to know what you're asking (e.g. describe what kind of rocking effect, maybe?). I'll close this question in the meantime to prevent wild guess answers from creating further confusion. You should edit your question, and later flag it for us to look at again.

Comment: you really never seen a rocking chair or so? If you trace it would look like an ellipse cut in half.

Comment: So you want an element to rotate back and forth? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake

You need of course to include jQuery UI, or at least parts of it.

EDIT:
After your elaboration, I think you are looking to animate the rotation, which can be done with CSS3.
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/

You can animate the position as well, if that helps you.

Comment: css3 will do. Thank you!